# Where to store GitLab/git credentials stored on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, git, gitlab, remote-desktop

I am trying to figure out where to store my personal access token (PAT) generate in GitLab on a remote Windows 10 environment to authenticate on that GitLab instance.

Assuming I already have a local git repo on a shared drive, I can log in to my environment as myself, authenticate and set my remote like this:

`git remote set-url https://{my username}:{my access token}@{repo name}.git`

This provides authentication for me and when I commit and push I am properly identified in the gitlab instance.

However, if I log out and a colleague logs in and comes into the same repo on the same shared drive the remote will be authenticated for me rather than them. That is the remote will look like this:

```
git remote -v
> origin  https://{my username}:{my access token}@{repo name}.git (fetch)
> origin  https://{my username}:{my access token}@{repo name}.git  (push)
```

This isn't any good because my colleague has to either a) reset the git remote anytime they want to use the remote or b) authenticate with my PAT. Can anyone recommend a way to store ones username and PAT such that the remote looks more like this:

```
git remote -v
> origin  https://{repo name}.git (fetch)
> origin  https://{repo name}.git  (push)
```

Comment: Use the windows credential manager (i hope it's there in win 10).

You can store the base URL and username/password that is later fetched by git bash

Comment: The first advice is: do not use shared repositories. Git is a **distributed** VCS.

Comment: @phd - completely valid observation. Enough internal constraints exist that I am exploring other options. It is also helpful to find out how to better store credentials.